# Problem looping through some custom data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working on some custom application built with Laravel on the backend
and some javascript on the frontend. I have some errors that I have
pulled from the backend and logging it in console tab.
Am trying to loop through the object containing array of error messages
and displaying the error messages in the DOM in an alert error field.
When I loop am getting only the keys displayed but I want the values.

**Javascript Object in console tab**

```
travellerEmail: Array [ "The traveller email field is required." ]
​
travellerId: Array [ "The traveller id field is required." ]
​
travellerKra: Array [ "The traveller kra field is required." ]
​
travellerPassport: Array [ "The traveller passport field is required." ]
```

**My logic**

```
 let validation = error.responseJSON.errors;
 //console.log(validation);

let errors = document.getElementById("errorDiv");
$(errors).css('display' , 'block');

for(vald in validation){    
    errors.innerHTML += vald + '\n';
}
```

**Markup Document to populate**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" id="errorDiv" role="alert" style="display: none;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Value am getting after running the logic above**

```
travellerPassport travellerKra travellerId travellerEmail
```

Comment: `for ... in` is meant to loop over objects. Use `array.forEach()` or similar. If for some reason you want to keep using `for ... in`, you have to get the value manually: `validation[ vald ]`.

Comment: You can use 'of' instead of 'in' in the for loop. /* for(vald of validation) */

Answer (score 0):

That's how `for` loops work.  If you want the value instead of the key, use `validation[vald]` inside your loop.

Comment: Thanks alot it works but the error messages are all displayed at once like a sentence, I need to display them in bullet points

Comment: Create an `<ul>` and append `<li>` elements to it so you get a default html list. The `list-type` can determine if you want bullet points, or numbers, or numerals or even an image as the bullet.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment: you'll want to loop over all the errors inside each error category.

```js
const errors = {
  travellerEmail: [
    "The traveller email field is required."
  ],
  travellerId: [
    "The traveller id field is required."
  ],
  travellerKra: [
    "The traveller kra field is required."
  ],
  travellerPassport: [
    "The traveller passport field is required."
  ]
};
const list = document.querySelector( '#errorList' );
Object.entries( errors ).forEach(([ errorType, errors ]) => {
  const listItems = errors.map( error => `<li>${ error }</li>` );
  list.innerHTML += listItems.join( '' );
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <ul class="alert alert-danger" id="errorList" role="alert"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```